# Componente com mesmo height

Tags: android, android-layout

Existe uma maneira de fazer com que um LinearLayout tenha o mesmo height que um TextView?

```
       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/blue"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/edit"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lista_imagem"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/avatar"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lista_nome"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lista_imagem"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lista_imagem"
            android:text="Titulo"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Eu queria que o

```
 android:layout_height=""
```

Do meu linear layout tivesse o mesmo tamanho do TextView `lista_nome`, lembrando que este deve ser `wrap_content` porque o texto muda de tamanho. Existe uma maneira de fazer isso? Sei que por dimen você define um valor padrão, mas teria uma forma de fazer esse valor ser igual ao do TextView, por exemplo?

Edit: O TextView não pode ficar dentro desse LinearLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível se feito no java.

Atribua um Id ao LinearLayout(`android:id="@+id/linearLayout"`) e no `onCreate()` adicione o seguinte código:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ...
    ...
    final LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    final TextView listaNome = findViewById(R.id.lista_nome);
    ...
    ...

    listaNome.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new

         ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
             @Override
             public void onGlobalLayout() {

                 //Remove o listenner para não ser novamente chamado.
                 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                     layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                 } else {
                     //noinspection deprecation
                     layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                 }

                 //Obtém os parâmetros do LinearLayout
                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
                 //Atribui a altura do TextView à altura do LinearLayout
                 layoutParams.height = listaNome.getHeight();
                 layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
             }
         });
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado ramaral, funcionou aqui

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma alternativa sem precisar usar o java:

```
<LinearLayout
          ...
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lista_nome"
          .../>
```

Comment: Isso só funciona nesse caso especifico, em que as views estão num RalativeLayout e nessa posição relativa entre elas.